# Deploying WAR from maven

Tags: java, maven, war

I wrote an integration test where the test starts an application server and deploys a WAR file in it. The test works fine when I run it from eclipse but when it is run from maven during building, it says that maven cant locate the WAR file. How do I make maven look into the directory for which the WAR file is in (where does maven look in by default?)

**EDIT**: So if I want to edit a `project.build.directory` property, would I go into my POM file and create the elements:

```
< project>  
 < build>  
  < directory>pathname< /directory>  
 < /build>  
< project>
```

Or is there more to changing a property?

Comment: You probably don't need to write that kind of code yourself, Maven is designed to handle deploying your WAR file for you. Did you use the maven webapp archetype to start with?

Comment: please post the relevant portion of your pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a property `${project.build.directory}` that results in the path to your "target" dir. (See: [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide))

Maybe that helps you?

Comment: How do I modify the properties?

Comment: I think you cannot modify this property. But you can define your own properties. See "Custom Properties in the POM" here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide